# How can the gnome3 activities hotspot be definitely disabled

Tags: gnome

I'm looking for a definitive solution to the problem of disabling the Gnome3 activities hotspot, if one exists. I find this feature disruptive and irritating and I really want it gone. So far I have installed the Activities Configurator and set Disable Hot Spot to ON and, for good measure, selected the smiley replacement for "Activities" text and cranked up the Hot Spot sensitivity to the max (250). The fact that the smiley face appeared is reassuring, at least the AC works in part. But what it doesn't do is completely disable the hotspot. This is still operating. It seems that a more radical solution is needed. Is there any other way to remove the hotspot functionality? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the GNOME extension page in your Firefox (doesn't work in Chrome) browser and open the [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) extension page and activate the extension:

[image]

- Tested with GNOME 3.16
- Supported GNOME versions today (2015-06-16)

  3.8, 3.10, 3.12, 3.14, 3.16, 3.18

From the description:

> This extension disables the top left hot corners. You can still click
>   on Activities or press the dedicated key to reach the overview. Since
>   3.8, should work with other extensions modifying the Activities button. On versions prior to 3.8, may not disable other hotcorners in
>   multiscreen configurations and won't work on fallback/flashback mode.

Comment: At last, freedom from the dreaded TLHC monster :). Thank you both kindly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the tweak tool on gnome to add the extension "No Topleft Hot Corner"

Answer (score -2):

The No Topleft Hot Corner extension can interfere with other extensions that try to detect/change this feature e.g. Gno-menu